# Django Cryptographic Signing

Tags: python, django

I have this:

**views.py**:

```
articles = Articles.objects.all()
```

and

**index.html**:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <div class = 'Article'>
        <h3 class='article-header'>{{article.header}}</h3>
        <p class='article-body'>{{article.content}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class = 'comment_wrapper'>
        <textarea class="comment" rows = '2' ></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' value = '{{article.id}}' class='article-id'>
        <div class = 'comment_buttons'>
            <button class="submit_comment btn" type="submit">Comment</button>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to `Sign` the `ID`s of the articles with Django's [Cryptographic Signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signing/) so that users cannot tamper with them and submit a comment to a wrong article. How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: Really? Cryptographic signing for *comment* submissions? Why would you bother?

Comment: I am saying articles IDs. I am using the value of the hidden input field to save to COMMENT TABLE via AJAX and if a user alter the value, the comment could get submitted to a wrong article.